# Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near ".":

Tags: android, sqlite, android-contentprovider

I am getting following error when I tried to update the rows in  database using content provider. please provide me some solution

```
id.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near ".": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: UPDATE birthTable SET birthday=?,name=? WHERE com.example.home.myapplication.test='com.app.aroundu'
```

and the code for content provider.

```
public class BirthProvider extends ContentProvider {
 // fields for my content provider
 static final String PROVIDER_NAME = "com.javacodegeeks.provider.Birthday";
 static final String URL = "content://" + PROVIDER_NAME + "/friends";
 static final Uri CONTENT_URI = Uri.parse(URL);

 // fields for the database
 static final String ID = "id";
 static final String NAME = "name";
 static final String BIRTHDAY = "birthday";

 // integer values used in content URI
 static final int FRIENDS = 1;
 static final int FRIENDS_ID = 2;

 DBHelper dbHelper;

 // projection map for a query
 private static HashMap<String, String> BirthMap;

 // maps content URI "patterns" to the integer values that were set above
 static final UriMatcher uriMatcher;
   static{
      uriMatcher = new UriMatcher(UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);
      uriMatcher.addURI(PROVIDER_NAME, "friends", FRIENDS);
      uriMatcher.addURI(PROVIDER_NAME, "friends/#", FRIENDS_ID);
   }

   // database declarations
   private SQLiteDatabase database;
   static final String DATABASE_NAME = "BirthdayReminder";
   static final String TABLE_NAME = "birthTable";
   static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
   static final String CREATE_TABLE = 
      " CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME +
      " (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + 
      " name TEXT NOT NULL, " +
      " birthday TEXT NOT NULL);";


   // class that creates and manages the provider's database 
   private static class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.w(DBHelper.class.getName(),
                "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                    + newVersion + ". Old data will be destroyed");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " +  TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
    }

   }

@Override
public boolean onCreate() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Context context = getContext();
    dbHelper = new DBHelper(context);
    // permissions to be writable
    database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

    if(database == null)
        return false;
    else
        return true;    
}

@Override
public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection,
        String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     SQLiteQueryBuilder queryBuilder = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
     // the TABLE_NAME to query on
     queryBuilder.setTables(TABLE_NAME);

      switch (uriMatcher.match(uri)) {
      // maps all database column names
      case FRIENDS:
          queryBuilder.setProjectionMap(BirthMap);
         break;
      case FRIENDS_ID:
          queryBuilder.appendWhere( ID + "=" + uri.getLastPathSegment());
         break;
      default:
         throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown URI " + uri);
      }
      if (sortOrder == null || sortOrder == ""){
         // No sorting-> sort on names by default
         sortOrder = NAME;
      }
      Cursor cursor = queryBuilder.query(database, projection, selection, 
              selectionArgs, null, null, sortOrder);
      /** 
       * register to watch a content URI for changes
       */
      cursor.setNotificationUri(getContext().getContentResolver(), uri);

      return cursor;
}

@Override
public Uri insert(Uri uri, ContentValues values) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    long row = database.insert(TABLE_NAME, "", values);

    // If record is added successfully
      if(row > 0) {
         Uri newUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(CONTENT_URI, row);
         getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(newUri, null);
         return newUri;
      }
      throw new SQLException("Fail to add a new record into " + uri);
}

@Override
public int update(Uri uri, ContentValues values, String selection,
        String[] selectionArgs) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     int count = 0;

      switch (uriMatcher.match(uri)){
      case FRIENDS:
         count = database.update(TABLE_NAME, values, selection, selectionArgs);
         break;
      case FRIENDS_ID:
         count = database.update(TABLE_NAME, values, ID + 
                 " = " + uri.getLastPathSegment() + 
                 (!TextUtils.isEmpty(selection) ? " AND (" +
                 selection + ')' : ""), selectionArgs);
         break;
      default: 
         throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unsupported URI " + uri );
      }
      getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
      return count;
}

@Override
public int delete(Uri uri, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int count = 0;

     switch (uriMatcher.match(uri)){
      case FRIENDS:
          // delete all the records of the table
          count = database.delete(TABLE_NAME, selection, selectionArgs);
          break;
      case FRIENDS_ID:
          String id = uri.getLastPathSegment(); //gets the id
          count = database.delete( TABLE_NAME, ID +  " = " + id + 
                (!TextUtils.isEmpty(selection) ? " AND (" + 
                selection + ')' : ""), selectionArgs);
          break;
      default: 
          throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unsupported URI " + uri);
      }

      getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
      return count;


}

@Override
public String getType(Uri uri) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (uriMatcher.match(uri)){
      // Get all friend-birthday records 
      case FRIENDS:
         return "vnd.android.cursor.dir/vnd.example.friends";
      // Get a particular friend 
      case FRIENDS_ID:
         return "vnd.android.cursor.item/vnd.example.friends";
      default:
         throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unsupported URI: " + uri);
      }
}
```

and the method call

```
 String URL = "content://com.javacodegeeks.provider.Birthday/friends";
              Uri friends = Uri.parse(URL);
              values.put(BirthProvider.BIRTHDAY, "true");
    getContentResolver().update(friends, values, values.get(BirthProvider.NAME)+"="+"'com.app.aroundu'", null);
```

What is the actual mistake done by me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> getContentResolver().update(friends, values, values.get(BirthProvider.NAME)+"="+"'com.app.aroundu'", null);
> ```

In here `values.get(BirthProvider.NAME)` returns a string `com.example.home.myapplication.test`which is not a syntactically valid column name.

Possibly you want just `BirthProvider.NAME` there.